# Can I add 2 Login features in One Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I drew an Use Case Model for Academic Calendar Application, and what am struggling with is the fact I put 2 login features in the same model. One for the academic advisor and one for the students.

So my question is: is it okay with this?
Or should I draw a line from actor academic advisor to the same feature as login for the students.

Last and important one: What does *Extends* means in dashed lines?

Here is my Model
[image]

Comment: Amazing how a question being completely off attracting so many people. The use case scene is obviously most confused :-(

Answer (score 1):

## In short

`Login` should in principle not be a use case.  But if you keep it, don’t duplicate it for different actors: prefer the addition association with the same use case, or better refactor your diagram to use generalization.

The extension means that `Change Profile Status` may in some situations enrich the behaviors and interactions of `Login`.

## More explanations

#### 1. Is the login a use-case at all?

There is no order among use cases, and a use case should be a reason for the actor to use the system. According to your diagram, an actor could use the system just for the sole purpose of `Login` (really?). Or do a `Managing schedule` without a login (oops).

This suggests that the **login is not a use-case** but a constraint, or an action in the activity diagrams that would describe each use case. (By the way, login is often obsolete in an era of Single Sign On that makes it happen behind the scene without user involvement; `autheticate user`) would be the corresponding action)

#### 2. Ambiguity of a use cases with several actors

The UML specification do not define the semantic of a use case with several actors. It can mean that one among several can perform the use-case (but multiplicity should be set accordingly), or that several or all are involved in the use case, but without telling if it’s at the sale time or one after the other.

In any case, it’s ambiguous, even if most of us get the intended meaning right when reading the diagram.

On the other side, **use-cases should not be duplicated to represent the same set of behaviors for different actors**.

#### Is there an alternative?

Two popular techniques help to disambiguate having several actors aiming for the sale use-case:

- generalization of actors: if a use-case is common to several actors, you could perhaps identify a base actor for all the common use-cases. In your diagram this would mean introducting an actor `User` and let `Student` and `Admin` inherit from `User`.
- disambiguate in the textual narrative that should be provided to describe each use case

Comment: my point of drawing a login use-case because it is connected to the college database (conceptual mode) and once the student downloads the app he/she needs to log in to his student id first in order to use the app properly.

Comment: @AHumaidi9 Hello! I get your point.  But it is not sufficient to justify a use-case. “the user downloads the app and he/she WANTS to manage tasks” or “the app should help him/her to to manage tasks” would be justification with evidence of added value. If you don’t  agree with this viewpoint, because you were taught to have login “use-cases”, then ignore point 1 and go to point 2 for a relevant answer. Nevertheless think back at innovation and the next time you use a system with biometric authentication or with single sign on, remember my answer and see how limiting a wrong use-case could be